# ¿Cómo trabajar con dos models en la misma variable Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    if(request()->ajax())
    {
        $data = Tbl_Perimetro::findOrFail($id);
        return response()->json(['result' => $data]);

    }
}
```

Quisiera en la variable $data trabajar con otro model llamado Tbl_Cartera, y así poder trabajar con el modelo Tbl_Perimetro y Tbl_Cartera simultaneamente... es necesario que Tbl_Cartera tambien se le asigne la variable $data.

Este es mi model Tbl_Perimetro

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tbl_Equipo_Postventaatc extends Model

{

protected $table = "tbl_equipo_postventaatcs";
protected $fillable = [
'asesor_id', 'carteras_id', 'supervisor_id', 'skillcontacs_id', 'workgroupcontacs_id', 'estatus'
];
protected $guarded = ['id'];


public function carteras(){

return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Tbl_Lista_Cartera', 'carteras_id');

}

public function perimetro(){

return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tbl_Perimetro', 'segmentacionatcs_id');

}
```

Y este es mi otro model Tbl_Equipopostventaatc... no se si tengo algún problema en las relaciones..

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tbl_Equipo_Postventaatc extends Model

{
protected $table = "tbl_equipo_postventaatcs";
protected $fillable = [
'asesor_id', 'carteras_id', 'supervisor_id', 'skillcontacs_id', 'workgroupcontacs_id', 'estatus'
];
protected $guarded = ['id'];


public function carteras(){

return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Tbl_Lista_Cartera', 'carteras_id');

}

public function perimetro(){

return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tbl_Perimetro', 'segmentacionatcs_id');

}

}
```

Tambien hay otro model que va ligado llamado Tbl_Cartera

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tbl_Lista_Cartera extends Model

{
protected $table = "tbl_lista_carteras";
protected $fillable = [
'cartera'
];
protected $guarded = ['id'];

public function perimetro(){

return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tbl_Equipo_Postventaatc', 'carteras_id');

}

}
```

Quisiera saber si he hecho las relaciones de manera adecuada, ya que no he encontrado la manera de saber si las he hecho bien o no

Comment: Si tu modelo `Tbl_Perimetro` esta relacionado con el modelo `Tbl_Cartera` puedes hacer algo como esto `$data = Tbl_Perimetro::with('cartera')->findOrFail($id);` 

Pero para darte una mejor respuesta puedes actualizar tu pregunta agregando tu modelo `Tbl_Perimetro`

Comment: Cuál es la finalidad de trabajar en una misma variable con ambos modelos?

Comment: Ya he actualizado mi pregunta amigo @GFlores98

Comment: Estoy editando la informacion con un modal usando javascript.. pero no logro hacer que me reconzca los datos del segundo modelo.. no se si sea por un problema en las relaciones @Aprendiz

Comment: he añadido el otro model tambien, ya que son tres los que quiero que esten relacionados

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasar toda la información que necesites con los modelos relacionados ( en este caso las relaciones `carteras` y `perimetro`) haciendo uso de la instrucción `with` de laravel ORM, de la siguiente manera:

```
$data = Tbl_Perimetro::with('carteras', 'perimetro')->findOrFail($id);
return response()->json(['result' => $data]);
```

En la vista modal que tengas, puedes acceder de la siguiente manera:

```
{{ $data->carteras->campo_de_tu_tabla }}
```

Para el caso de perimetro se trata de una relacion `hasMany` por lo que deberas recorrelo con una estructura foreach, suponiendo que usas blade para consumir tu información:

```
  @foreach($data->perimetro as $item)
      $item->nombre_del_campo
  @endforeach
```

Comment: $data = Tbl_Perimetro::with('carteras', 'perimetro')->findOrFail($id); ......... carteras y perimetro vendrian siendo el nombre de las tablas de los otros modelos?

Comment: `carteras` hace referencia a la relación de tu modelo 
`public function carteras()`

Comment: gracias por responder, pero por alguna razon se me deshabilita el boton edit que activa el modal, tienes alguna idea del por que?

Comment: Deberías indicar en tu respuesta que relaciones conlleva y el por qué pues me parece las estás asumiendo

Comment: @Oscar tendrias que evaluar si tienes alguna condición para habilitar o deshabilitar el btn, no tengo idea del porque sin ver código

Comment: no.. ya he podido resolver pero igualmente sigo sin poder visualizar los datos de Tbl_Equipopostventaatc en mi modal